# Running multiple macros on different sheets with one button

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have one with 2 macros:

- The first one deletes any data on sheet2 column1
- The second sorts two columns on sheet1 and puts data on sheet2 column1.

[image]

I would like to run them both with one click. How do I do this?

Comment: Make the first macro call the second just before it exits?

Comment: I have include a screen shot. I'm stuck. Please tell me what to put where.

Comment: [How to Call or Run a Another Macro From a Macro - Excel Campus](https://www.excelcampus.com/library/vba-call-statement-run-macro-from-macro/)

Comment: @SITTB, your first Macro is Deleting Col A value in sheet1 and the Second Macro is comparing two Columns and Copy unmatched Values in another Sheet ,write!!

Answer (score 0):

**On the basis of the attached Screen Shot I found that you have two VBA Macro and you are trying to compare two Columns and Copy unmatched values into another Sheet.**

*For this you need method do combine two Macros into One.*

I would like to suggest method, will compare two Columns in source Sheet for unmatched value and Copy data into another Sheet.

Macro will apply Color Format on Rows and after Copy, reverse the Format from both Columns.

```
Sub HighlightColumnDifferences()

    Dim bothcolumns As Range, i As Integer

    Set bothcolumns = Selection

    With bothcolumns

        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count

            If Not StrComp(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

                Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

            End If

        Next i

    End With

Call Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 10
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
            Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
            Range("B" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next i

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("A1:B10").ClearFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- **Copy** & **Paste** both Code as Standard 
  Module.
- Select Data from both Columns in `Sheet 1`, you 
  want to compare.
- **RUN** `HighlightColumnDifferences` Macro.

**N.B.**

- You may Select any two columns to Compare 
  rather than only A & B.
- You may adjust values for `For i = 1 To 10`, 
  `Sheet Name` and Data Range `A1:B10` in Second 
  Macro.